# How can I feed 2" PE pipe through a slab--asking about bend radius?

Tags: water, concrete, pipe, slab

I'm trying to set sleeves for a monolithic slab pour. One of the sleeves is intended for running 2" water line. I wanted to use HDPE SIDR pipe aka flexible poly pipe. I can't find bend ratios for SIDR pipe, but I tried to use DR pipe ratios as a first pass estimate. It turns out the smallest bend I can make is a radius of 50" before the pipe will kink. I'm using 2" to limit pressure loss to 5 psi over 550 ft. Slab is 6" above grade, footer is 18" deep, trench is 30" deep.

1. Is 2" SIDR pipe similar in flexibility to DR pipe?
2. What is the largest SIDR pipe that can sweep directly through slab from trench in the given 36" radius?

Comment: A practical check on bend radius is to look at the inside diameter of a coil of the pipe in question, and divide by 2. Unfortunately for you, I don't have any 2" poly pipe on hand.

Comment: This is 4 different questions in 1, and we don't work well that way. As for #2, I'm sure someone _has_ done so, somewhere in the world, the important question is whether doing so is _legal_ in your part of the world.

Answer (score 1):

I have, in fact used electrical conduit for running waterlines through a concrete pour. IIRC (20 years ago now...) it was 1-1/2" or 2" conduit and 1" 160PSI poly (200 PSI down the well, but the surface run was 160 as it's under less pressure by 100-300 feet of head.)

I bent the conduit with careful application of hot water and force, rather than buying or renting a conduit heating blanket for bending PVC, or buying a pre-made sweep. Radius was about 36"

Comment: Thanks. That was very helpful! 
I did drive into the city to a supply house that had 2" poly SIDR7 (250 psi) and it was super stiff. There is no way it will bend through a 90 degree arc from a 30" trench up through a 4" slab in any kind of radius that makes it useful. It MIGHT have a 5 or 6 foot minimum bend radius, but it seems that would require machinery. It looked like two people in the field might be able to achieve a bend radius of approximately 10' at best.